# Get rollup group value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following data:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 3 |

I want a query which returns the following output.

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| Subtotal: A | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| Subtotal: B | 6 |

I am able to get "Subtotal" with `group by rollup` query but I want to get subtotal along with group column value.

Please help me with some SQL code

Answer (score 1):

If `score` has at most one value per `name, you can use` GROUPING SETS`:

```
select name, sum(score) as score
from t
group by grouping sets ((name, score), (name));
```

If `name` is never `null`, I would just use:

```
coalesce(name, 'Grouping ' + name)
```

Otherwise you need to use `grouping()`.

Comment: This query will give multiple groups but I want value of group in subtotal row.

Comment: @Hardik Change `select name` to `select case when GROUPING_ID(name, score) = 1 then 'subtotal: ' + name else name end`